# Linq2Entities Include with Skip / Take - load issue

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq-to-entities

*Note: I know there are a number of questions around for issues with Linq's .Include(table) not loading data, I believe I have exhausted the options people have listed, and still had problems.*

I have a large Linq2Entities query on an application I'm maintaining. The query is built up as such:

```
IQueryable<Results> query = context.MyTable
    .Where(r =>
    r.RelatedTable.ID == 2 &&
    r.AnotherRelatedTable.ID == someId);
```

Then predicates are built up depending on various business logic, such as:

```
if (sortColumn.Contains("dob "))
{
    if (orderByAscending)
        query = query.OrderBy(p => p.RelatedTable.OrderByDescending(q => q.ID).FirstOrDefault().FieldName);
    else
        query = query.OrderByDescending(p => p.RelatedTable.OrderByDescending(q => q.ID).FirstOrDefault().FieldName);
}
```

Note - there is always a sort order provided.

Originally the included tables were set at the beginning, after reading articles such as the famous [Tip 22](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/alexj/archive/2009/06/02/tip-22-how-to-make-include-really-include.aspx), so now they are done at the end (which didn't fix the problem):

```
var resultsList = (query.Select(r => r) as ObjectQuery<Results>)
    .Include("RelatedTable")
    .Include("AnotherRelatedTable")
    .Skip((page - 1) * rowsPerPage)
    .Take(rowsPerPage);
```

Seemingly at random (approximately for every 5000 users of the site, this issue happens once) the RelatedTable data won't load. It can be brute forced by calling load on the related table. But even the failure to load isn't consistent, I've run the query in testing and it's worked, but most of the time hasn't, without changing any code or data.

It is fine, when the skip and take aren't included, and the whole dataset is returned, but I would expect the skip and take to be done on the complete dataset - it certainly appears to be from profiling the SQL...

**UPDATE 16/11/10:** I have profiled the SQL against a problem data set, and I've been able to reproduce the query failing about 9/10 times, but succeeding the rest. The SQL being executed is identical when the query fails or succeeds except, as expected, for the parameters passed to the SQL.

The issue has been solved with the following change, but the question remains as to why this should be.

Failing - get LINQ to handle the rows:

```
var resultsList = (query.Select(r => r) as ObjectQuery<Results>)
    .Include("RelatedTable")
    .Include("AnotherRelatedTable")
    .Skip((page - 1) * rowsPerPage)
    .Take(rowsPerPage)
    .ToList();
```

Working - enumerate the data then get the rows:

```
var resultsList = (query.Select(r => r) as ObjectQuery<Results>)
    .Include("RelatedTable")
    .Include("AnotherRelatedTable")
    .ToList()
    .Skip((page - 1) * rowsPerPage)
    .Take(rowsPerPage);
```

Unfortunately the SQL this query creates contains some sensitive schema data so I can't post it, it is also 1400 lines long, so I wouldn't subject the public to it anyway!

Comment: Sorry, L2E...don't know why I was writing L2SQL!

Comment: So you are saying the SQL is the same for a working query request vs a query request that fails?

Comment: Unfortunately, when I have data that has this issue, the successful queries are very sporadic and I haven't managed to capture the SQL in profiler to compare. However I have no reason to suspect it would be different as it's been observed when there have been no code changes or predicate changes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The sole effect of `Take()` is to change the generated SQL. Other than that, the Entity Framework does not care about it at all. Same for `.Skip()`. It's hard to believe that this would have an effect on query materialization (although stranger things have happened).

So what *could* be causing this behavior? Off the top of my head:

1. A bug in your application or mapping which is causing an incorrect query to be generated.
2. A bug in the Entity Framework which would cause returned data to be materialized into objects incorrectly in certain circumstances.
3. Bad data in your database.
4. A bug in your database's SQL parser.

I don't think you're going to get a lot further with this until you can capture the generated SQL and run it yourself. This is actually not terribly hard, as you can set up a SQL profiler with an appropriate filter. If you find that the generated SQL is different in the buggy case, you can work backwards from there. If you find that the generated SQL is identical in the buggy case, the next step would be to look at the rows returned, preferably in the same context as the application ran it.

In short, I think you just have to keep tweaking your SQL profiling until you have the information you need.

Comment: I would move number 3 above number 2.  When in doubt, assume your code/data is wrong, not your tools.

Comment: Thanks Craig. I couldn't agree more that the most likely answer is my data. Interestingly at present I've worked around it by enumerating the query into a list, then doing the skip and take on the list. This works just fine...not sure exactly what that means for the issue! I'm going to try and have another crack at profiling the good / bad query over the next few days, I agree in principle this is the best option, but scarily the generated sql is 2000 lines long. Someone picked the wrong tool for the job me thinks! :P

Comment: 2000 lines? Shrug. It should differ only by params, right? If not, you probably found the problem....